# Trying to push an element in to a vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, explicit

In a header file (which I haven't written), a struct has been defined like this

```
struct MemoryMessage : public boost::counted_base { /*, public FastAlloc*/
  explicit MemoryMessage(MemoryMessageType aType)
   : theType(aType) {}
  explicit MemoryMessage(MemoryMessageType aType, MemoryAddress anAddress)
   : theType(aType) {}
  explicit MemoryMessage(MemoryMessageType aType, MemoryAddress anAddress, int anIdentifier)
   : theType(aType) {}
  explicit MemoryMessage(MemoryMessageType aType, MemoryAddress anAddress, VirtualMemoryAddress aPC)
   : theType(aType) {}
  explicit MemoryMessage(MemoryMessageType aType, MemoryAddress anAddress, VirtualMemoryAddress aPC, DataWord aData)
   : theType(aType) {}
  explicit MemoryMessage(MemoryMessage & aMsg)
   : theType(aMsg.theType) {} 
}
```

Later in my code, I have written

```
MemoryMessage testMsg;
class foo() {
  foo()
   : testMsg(MemoryMessage::test)
  {}
  std::vector< MemoryMessage > candidates;

  void bar() {
     candidates.push_back(testMsg);   
  }
}
```

But I get this error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'MemoryMessage::MemoryMessage(const MemoryMessage&)’
note: candidates are:MemoryMessage::MemoryMessage(MemoryMessage&)
```

What is wrong with that? I created a very small snippet. Please let me know if I missed something in my explanation.

Comment: Change `explicit MemoryMessage(MemoryMessage & aMsg)` to `MemoryMessage(const MemoryMessage & aMsg)`

Comment: Check the error message again, and compare what the compiler looks for to your copy-constructor.

Comment: @Dieter Lücking: That is right. But I need a solution for the code that I wrote (three lines). I don't want to change the `explicit` section

Comment: Try `.emplace_back` instead of `.push_back`.

Comment: What C++ compiler are you using?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: g++-4.4

Comment: I am trying this on ideone. Does your `MemoryMessage testMsg;` declaration compile? I do not see a parameterless constructor.

Comment: You are right. the correct syntax has been updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line behind the scene invokes a copy constructor:

```
candidates.push_back(testMsg);
```

The `testMsg` that `push_back` takes by `const` reference is placed into the vector by invoking a copy constructor inside `std::vector`'s code. However, your constructor is declared `explicit`, so `std::vector`'s code cannot access it.

Removing `explicit` designator from the copy constructor will fix this problem.

Comment: No I don't want to remove the `explicit` because it is the core of many other things. What can I do for the three lines that I wrote?

Comment: @mahmood Having an explicit copy-constructor almost never makes any sense, especially if all other constructors are marked explicit.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: Are you sure that changing `explicit MemoryMessage(MemoryMessage & aMsg)` to `MemoryMessage(MemoryMessage & aMsg)` and leaving other things intact will fix the error?

Comment: @mahmood [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) is what the signature of the copy constructor looks like. So you need it to take a `const &`. You could also simply leave it up to the compiler and ask for the default constructor, if that will be good enough.

Comment: Although removing the explicit will fix the error, still I am looking for another solution that keeps the explicit and can push back an element in to a vector