# copy constructor error with example

Tags: c++, vector, copy-constructor

Extending my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474684/trying-to-push-an-element-in-to-a-vector), I can not understand, why this code fails. There is no explicit statement here.

```
#include <vector>

class foo {
public:
   int num;
   int type;

   foo()
    : num(0)
    , type(0)
   {}
   foo(foo &a)
    : num(a.num)
    , type(a.type)
   {}
};

int main()
{
   foo theFoo;
   theFoo.num = 10;
   theFoo.type = 2;
   std::vector< foo > theVec;
   theVec.push_back(theFoo);
   return 0;
}
```

The error is

```
no matching function for call to ‘foo::foo(const foo&)’
mytest.cpp:12: note: candidates are: foo::foo(foo&)
mytest.cpp:8: note:                 foo::foo()
```

Can someone clearly explain what is going wrong here?

Comment: change `foo(foo &a)` to `foo(const foo &a)`. The "true" copy constructor takes a `const` reference.

Comment: The error is the same as what I got in the link. The culprit there was `explicit`. Now why should I get the same error?

Comment: How explicit should the error message be? Just read it...

Comment: @Deduplicator: He means the `explicit` keyword, I guess...

Comment: @quantdev: I know, but I'm not using it as a keyword there.

Comment: @mahmood: For the reason that Alexandru describes in his comment.

Comment: oh ok.
@OP, the type of a vector must be const copy constructible, its a requirement. Yours is not. Do way the compiler says and provide `foo(const foo &a)`

Comment: Putting `= 0` behind the member `int` declarations and removing all ctors would actually work even better in the example.

Comment: Sorry, where exactly? `foo(foo &a = 0)` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is clear enough. In statement

```
theVec.push_back(theFoo);
```

there is used member function of class std::vector `push_back` that is declared in the class the following way

```
void push_back(const T& x);
```

As you see the parameter is defined as const reference. So to copy the object x into the container the type of the object has to have copy construtor declared as

```
T( const T & );
```

Or in your case as

```
foo( const foo &a );
```

But your class has no such a constructor. So the compiler issues the error.

Comment: That is right. One more thing... How can I push_back if the foo constructor is defined with `explicit` keyword?

Comment: @mahmood You can use emplace_back

Comment: g++4.4 has no such member for vector

Comment: @mahmood Why do not you want to define the required copy constructor?

Comment: @mahmood You could simply use the implicit copy constructor by not defining it explicitly. Simply remove your copy constructor.

Comment: Anyway. I was looking for a solution to keep exlicit. Because the explicit part is not my code. What I should do is to play with the object and the way that I want to push_back it.